# how can i use float left for n-th child

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

i have foreach loop for div contain image and data
i want to make even index image float to left and data float to right
and odd index float data to left and image to right
but its not working

```css
.row.front-page-category:nth-child(even) .imagecard {
  float: left;
}

.row.front-page-category:nth-child(even) .details-card {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container p-2 front-page-slider">
  @foreach ($cars as $car)
  <div class="row front-page-category shadow-sm mt-3 rounded" data-aos="fade-{{ $loop->index%2 ? 'left' : 'right' }}" data-aos-duration="1000">

    <div class="imagecard w-50 ">
      <img src="{{asset('images/'.$car->image)}}" class="card-img-top-slider float-end user" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="continer details-card w-25">
      <div>{{($car->brand) }}</div>
      <div>{{($car->price) }} </div>
      <div>{{($car->type) }} </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  @endforeach

</div>
```

```html
<div class="container p-2 front-page-slider">
  @foreach ($cars as $car)
  <div class="row front-page-category shadow-sm mt-3 rounded" data-aos="fade-{{ $loop->index%2 ? 'left' : 'right' }}" data-aos-duration="1000">

    <div class="imagecard w-50 m{{ $loop->index%2 ? 'l' : 'r' }}-auto">
      <img src="{{asset('images/'.$car->image)}}" class="card-img-top-slider float-end user" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="continer details-card w-25">
      <div>{{($car->brand) }}</div>
      <div>{{($car->price) }} </div>
      <div>{{($car->type) }} </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  @endforeach

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove these float related classes in the image and other divs

Comment: removing all other classes ?
you wrote continer maybe it is also related

Comment: i removed it all but still nothing changed even i did hashed bootstrap link

Comment: it might be realted to the aos library you use for fades maybe it ads float styling ?

Comment: okey its working but i have to use bootstrap to be responsive

Comment: Not good practice but then use => float: right !important;

Comment: its works when i used  .container  but it stopped working when i used .row do you know why ?

Comment: you can open your browser and checkout devtools the styling Strikethrough of floats

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add float styles to both even and odd children like in my snippet down below.

```css
.row > .left {
  width: 50%; height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.row > .right {
  width: 25%; height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) > .left  {
  float: left;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) > .right  {
  float: right;
}
.row:nth-child(even) > .left  {
  float: right;
}
.row:nth-child(even) > .right  {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what is wrong with my code ? do you know ?

Comment: even this code not working with me in my editor

Comment: @HossamThapet try removing container class from <div class="continer details-card w-25">, maybe it overwrites css

Comment: @HossamThapet I suggest removing all classes and even the fade animation, and then start adding them back one by one and you will see where the problem starts to appear :)

Comment: it happens when i use   . row class